# Annoying React Error... "TypeError: Cannot read property 'My_Items' of null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a child component I need to pass an object to via props and find an index value inside an array within that object. If you look at the code below it is fairly straightforward.

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'My_Items' of null
```

I've tried initializing the 'My_Items' array a bunch of different ways but I still get the error.

How can I access those values in that array from the IndexComponent and avoid this error?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

function IndexComponent(props) {
  const {
    typeName,
    myObject
  } = props;


  const getAtIndex = (type) => { //this function retrieves the index of the desired item inside the My_Items array, inside the larger object
    let index;
      myObject.My_Items.map(item => {
      if(item.title === type) {
      index = myObject.My_Items.indexOf(item);
      }
    })
    return index;
  }

    return (
      <div>
        My Desired Index Value: {getAtIndex(typeName)} <br/>
      </div>
    )
}

class MyComponent extends Component {

  render() {

    const {
      typeName,
      myObject
    } = this.props;


    return (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xl-5">

              <IndexComponent typeName={typeName} myObject={myObject} />

            </div>
          </div>
)}

export default connect(
  (store) => {
    return {
      typeName: store.data.typeName,
      myObject: store.data.myObject
    };
  }
)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `myObject` is null, not `My_Items`.

Comment: Are you sure that `store.data.myObject` shouldn't be `store.myObject`? Can you show us your Redux store?

Comment: @stybl ok the thing is it isn't null, I can console.log the object and prints just fine.. how do I make it see the data?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `MyComponent` (and `IndexComponent`) rendering starts before `store.data.myObject` is initialized. I would recommend to

1) check the initial redux state; there should be something like

```
data: {
  myObject: {
    My_Items: [],
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

2) protect `IndexComponent` render in a way like

```
return myObject && myObject.My_Items && myObject.My_Items.length ? (
  <div>
    My Desired Index Value: {getAtIndex(typeName)} <br/>
  </div>
) : ( null )
```

or with p.(1)

```
return myObject.My_Items.length ? (
  <div>
    My Desired Index Value: {getAtIndex(typeName)} <br/>
  </div>
) : ( null )
```